# Druids' access to Domains in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid

In Pathfinder, does a Druid gain access to two Domains like the cleric? If he does, would it be the elemental types such as Fire, Water, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Druids get [Nature Bond](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/druid.html) at first level. If they abstain from an animal companion, then they can choose a Cleric domain: Air, Animal, Earth, Fire, Plant, Water, or Weather. *Ultimate Magic* adds [several new Druid domains](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/druid.html): Aquatic, Arctic, Cave, Desert, Eagle, Frog, Jungle, Monkey, Mountain, Plains, Serpent, Swamp, or Wolf.

I can't seem to find a method that lets a pure Druid have more than one domain, but I'm sure someone will chime in if there's a way.

Comment: Ah I see, I totally over-looked Nature Bond! Thank you so much!!